# mouse click event on row in Data Grid in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How to handle mouse click on a row in Datagrid in C#

for eg if i m populating a table from my database in a data grid and when i select a row .i should be able to go to a different page and display the contents of that row in text boxes .is it possible to do that in c#

Comment: You'd have to [implement clicking yourself](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/dgrowselect.aspx), or you could always edit the template and have it insert a hyperlink in to each row that would do the same.

Comment: What are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `SelectionChanged` event of DataGridView and use `DataGridView1.SelectedRows` collection to get reference of selected row(s).

```
if(DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count!=0)
{
  str = DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
}
```